# how to implement jquery selectable on dynamically created object

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am using jquery [selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/) . This is my code:-

```
$('#selectable').bind("mousedown", function(e) {e.metaKey = true;}).selectable();
```

This works fine on existing object which loads at loading time. How to implement jquery selectable on dynamically created objects?

I tried the code given below- but it gives a problem.

```
$(document).bind("mousedown", "#selectable", function(e) {
    e.metaKey = true;
    $(this).selectable();
});
```

1. It does not work on first click, but selection happens only after
   second click.
2. It does not unselect an object when clicked for second
   time.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `refresh` option of the jquery-ui selectable plugin. More Informations do you find at the [docs of jquery-ui](https://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#method-refresh).

I have created a simple example here, which I hope will help you.

```js
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  $target = $('#selectable');

$target.selectable();

setTimeout(function() {
  // this code will run after 3 seconds
  $target.empty();

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    $target.append('<li>Item ' + ('0' + items[i]).slice(-2) + '</li>');
  }

  $target.selectable('refresh');
}, 3000);
```

```css
#selectable {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#selectable li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 2px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#selectable li.ui-selected {
  background-color: #0c0;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ol id="selectable">
  <li>Wait 3 Seconds ...</li>
</ol>
```